# while replacing the fragment view pager the viewpager fragment shows blank

Tags: java, android, json

I am calling the view pager fragments by replacing over frame layout but when when i call it again the last loaded fragments of view pager are shown blank.

//Here I am replacing the view pager fragment in main activity

```
All_Women_Categories fragment = new All_Women_Categories();

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

//Here is my called view pager fragment

```
public class All_Ethnic_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private static ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_women_ethnic_view_pager,
                container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.women_ethnic_pager);



            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        return rootView;
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Sarees.newInstance("Hello");
            case 1:
                return Lehengas.newInstance("Hello");
            case 2:
                return Salwars_n_Churidars.newInstance("Hello");
            case 3:
                return Kurtis.newInstance("Hello");
            case 4:
                return Dress_Materials.newInstance("Hello");
            case 5:
                return Stitched_Suits.newInstance("Hello");

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.sarees).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.lehngas).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.salwars).toUpperCase();
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.kurti).toUpperCase();
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.dress_material).toUpperCase();
            case 5:
                return getString(R.string.stiched).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone get anything that what's happening then please tell me..
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your question, but I think you should stack fragments instead of replacing them. Instead of

```
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

You should try using `add(Fragment fragment)`, `remove()` and/or `show(Fragment fragment)`. In this way, you may add all of your fragments first, and then decide to show/hide them as appropriate.

Comment: actually i am using drawer layout with listview items with every item click i have to show different fragments with view pager .. so can u tell me what should i use, replace or add, hide and show fragment.